# Create a new column with a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table full of dates, the dates are unique but for each date I want to have numbers 1-3. So as it stands now all the dates are distinct but my objective is to have a new column where each date has 3 rows instead of one with the numbers 1-3.

Right now my table looks like this:

```
Date
1/1/2016
2/1/2016
```

What I want is this:

```
Date     | Number
1/1/2016 | 1
1/1/2016 | 2
1/1/2016 | 3
2/1/2016 | 1
2/1/2016 | 2
2/1/2016 | 3
```

Is this possible with a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cross join` with `generate_series`.

```
select d.dt,n.num
from dates_tbl d
cross join generate_series(1,3) n(num)
```

Comment: Worked perfect! thank you I didn't know about the generate_series function.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a number of ways.

Here's one:

start by modify the table to add the additional number field. 
then create a table and insert the values 1, 2, 3 into the table as three different rows. If you only want to do this as a one-off you could do this as a temp table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_location
(
   number int
) 
ON COMMIT DROP;
```

INSERT into your table with the new field the results of a `CROSS JOIN` with the numbers table and your dates.